# Adding a Line in Excel VBA, Changing the thickness and drawing "up"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to draw lines with Excel VBA and it is working nicely except for 2 things,
1) How do I make the line thicker?
2) The lines that go up and to the right do not get drawn.  The ones that are horizontal or go down and to the right draw just fine.

Here is my code:

```
Sub DrawLine(FromCell As Range, ToCell As Range)
 With FromCell.Parent.Shapes.AddLine(1, 1, 1, 1)
  .Left = FromCell.Left + (FromCell.Width)
  .Top = FromCell.Top + (FromCell.Height)
  .Width = (ToCell.Left) - .Left
  .Height = (ToCell.Top + (ToCell.Height)) - .Top
 End With
End Sub

Sub GoDraw()
 Call DrawLine(Range("D3"), Range("H3"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D3"), Range("H7"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D3"), Range("H11"))

 Call DrawLine(Range("D7"), Range("H3"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D7"), Range("H7"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D7"), Range("H11"))

 Call DrawLine(Range("D11"), Range("H3"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D11"), Range("H7"))
 Call DrawLine(Range("D11"), Range("H11"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article I wrote a few years ago on programming shapes with VBA. See the "Adding Connectors and Lines" section.

http://www.breezetree.com/articles/excel-2007-autoshapes-vba.htm

The lines that go "up and to the right" are called elbow connectors, and you can set that by setting the MsoConnectorType variable when adding a line.

Comment: Awesome!  I had no idea Excel did this sort of Visio stuff!

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the link.  Great article.  I don't think I was very clear when I said lines that go "up and to the right".  I don't want the connectors that change directions, I need a straight line that goes from, for example, A3 to C1.  For some reason the lines will only draw if they are horizontal or downward sloping, but not upward sloping.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Unfortunately, Excel provides very little control over routing the end points of free-standing lines. What I do is set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, add one small rectangle at the start point, another small rectangle at the end point, add a connector between them, and then delete the rectangles and set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.